# A model to detect the differences between 2 similar images

Tags: python, machine-learning, image-processing, deep-learning, computer-vision

In my work I came across the following machine learning issue:
My product is doing an inspection on semiconductor components. The product is going to receive the following input from the machine that the components are passing across. The machine will provide for me:

1. An image of the component that has been just inspected. (we call it the inspected image)
2. An image of the component in the ideal shape and state. (we call it the template)
3. A 3D depth map of the inspected image.
4. A 3D depth map of the template.

**Take note that the inspected image and template can't be identical even if the inspected image has the ideal shape and state. This is because the camera shifting when taking these images is pretty common and not avoidable**

I want to train a model, that can take the template + the inspected image as an input and be able to bound box the differences between these 2 images on the inspected image. The differences I want to detect are specific and related to material changes only -not other difference like color changes for example- where there is an extra material on the inspected image like an extra solder or a crack in the component.
What kind of a model/architecture can be used for this problem? And how to choose the loss function for such and issue?

I tried the Siamese network, but it had 2 flaws in my case:

1. When training on a mix of obvious differences and small differences, the model in prediction mode is able to detect only the major differences. If the template and inspected image have only minor differences, the model was not able to detect that there is something wrong between these 2 images.
2. I want my model to focus on small differences also, this is why I come up with the idea of bounding boxes for the differences, which the Siamese model is not able to output.

Also, when I tried some image processing libraries to detect differences, the results were naïve, because in the production line, template and inspected image can't be exactly the same due to camera shifting.